# Filter list items

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a list of items i pull from SharePoint and want to filter them in my custom list view page.

So my function works exactly how I want it but it seems messy and I'm hoping someone could point me to or explain a better way of achieving this or an "optimized" version of what I did.

I'm using a for loop with if to compare the values and display only when true.
I have multiple filters and this is where it became tricky to me.

In below code example:

- `incarr` array contains the list items.
- arri = number of items in list received from SharePoint list

Code:

```
function displaytable() {                               
    document.getElementById("myHTMLTable").innerHTML = "";
    $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
  "<th align='left'>"+"<b>Systems Affected</b>"+"</th>" +
  "<th width= 5% align='left'>"+"<b>Incident Date</b>"+"</th>" +                   
    "<th align='left'>"+"<b>Incident Number</b>"+"</th>" +
  "<th align='left'>"+"<b>Root Cause</b>"+"</th>" +
    "<th align='left'>"+"<b>Description</b>"+"</th>" + 
    "<th width= 6% align='left'>"+"<b>Attachments</b>"+"</th>" +                                         
  "</tr>");                 
    var filtery = document.getElementById("dropdownyear").value;
    var filterm = document.getElementById("dropdownmonth").value.toUpperCase();
    var filters = document.getElementById("dropdownsystem").value.toUpperCase();
    var filtersev = document.getElementById("dropdownseverity").value.toUpperCase();                
    for (i=0;i<arri;i++){
        //manual if statements until I can figure our a more effective way                                  
        if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && incarr[i][5] == filterm && incarr[i][0].toUpperCase() == filters && filtersev == incarr[i][7].toUpperCase()){                                                
            $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +  //full filter
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" + 
            "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +
            "</tr>");                       
        } else if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && incarr[i][5] == filterm && filters == "SYSTEM" && filtersev == incarr[i][7].toUpperCase() ) {
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //system filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                                                    
        "</tr>");
        } else if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && filterm == "MONTH" && incarr[i][0].toUpperCase() == filters && filtersev == incarr[i][7].toUpperCase() ){
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //Month filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                           
        "</tr>");
        } else if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && filterm == "MONTH" && filters == "SYSTEM" && filtersev ==  incarr[i][7].toUpperCase() ){
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //Month & System filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                          
        "</tr>");
        } else if (filtery == "YEAR" && filterm == "MONTH" && incarr[i][0].toUpperCase() == filters && filtersev == incarr[i][7].toUpperCase() ){
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //Year & Month filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                           
                "</tr>");
        } else if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && incarr[i][5] == filterm && filters == "SYSTEM" && filtersev == "SEVERITY" ) {
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //system, severity filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                           
        "</tr>");
        } else if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && filterm == "MONTH" && incarr[i][0].toUpperCase() == filters && filtersev == "SEVERITY" ){
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //Month, severity filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                            
        "</tr>");
        } else if (incarr[i][6] == filtery && filterm == "MONTH" && filters == "SYSTEM" && filtersev == "SEVERITY" ){
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +  //Month & System & Severity filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                            
        "</tr>");
        } else if (filtery == incarr[i][6] &&  filterm == incarr[i][5] && incarr[i][0].toUpperCase() == filters && filtersev == "SEVERITY"){                                                                    
                $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +  //Severity filter all
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" +
                "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +                                           
                "</tr>");
        };
    }                           
}
```

when selecting a filter it must only display items matching that column, and I must be able to select multiple filters to filter the filtered list (if this makes sense?)

Comment: if it works as intended but you need a codereview, then you should rather post your question on [codereview.se] :)

Comment: Use `Array#filter` on the source array, where your predicate calls `Array#every` on an array of required filter predicates

Comment: @Icepickle thanks I did not know about Code Review I will go ahead and post it there now :)

Comment: @tehhowch thanks, I did a quick google search on this and it seems like a good way to go about, I reposted this question on Code Review, you are welcome to post this as an answer.

Comment: Code review link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224210/filter-list-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you can split this duplicated code to separate function and reuse it

```
$("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +  //full filter
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" + 
            "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +
            "</tr>");
```

Example:

```
function appendTableRow(incarr) {
   $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][0]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][1]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][2]+"</td>" +  //full filter
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][3]+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][4]+"</td>" + 
            "<td align='left'>"+incarr[i][8]+"</td>" +
            "</tr>");   
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, will this assist with performance or just for readability?

Comment: @phat this function should take a specific array element as an argument, i.e. `appendRow(incarr[i])`, rather than require `i` to have global or outer scoping.

Comment: @tehowch Thanks. My mistake, It should have `i` as a parameter as well.
@SqueakyDeath for readability and maintainbility

Comment: thanks for answer, i will add this and suggestions I got on code review.